# Lorentz spinor in Lorentz $\rm Spin(3,1)$ signature and the real structure?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, group-theory, representation-theory, wick-rotation

In this paper:

- J. Wang, X. Wen and E. Witten, "A new ${\rm SU}(2)$ anomaly", [J. Math. Phys. **60** (2019) 052301](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5082852), [arXiv:1810.00844](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.00844),

it says the following in p.2,

[image]

> It says for $3+1$ dimensional spacetime, the Weyl spinor with $SU(2)$ isospin $1/2$ , "Lorentz signature always carry a real structure; if a fermion field appears in the Lagrangian, so does its hermitian adjoint"

What does it mean to be  **real** ? If :

- Weyl spinor is **complex** in $\text {Spin}(3,1)$, and
- its $SU(2)$ isospin $1/2$ is **pseudoreal** in $SU(2) = \text {Spin} (3)$,

why do we get a Lorentz signature always carry a real structure (instead of just complex or pseudoreal)? Does it mean the whole  Weyl spinor is in a real representation (4 component) of $\text {Spin} (3,1)$ and $SU(2) $ together?

What is the emphasis to say "In the Euclidean signature, nothing like that is true in general; what happens depends on the spacetime dimension"? Isnt that the Lorentz signature : real, pseudoreal, or complex also depends on the spacetime dimension ?

Answer (score 1):

The highlighted statement is quite gnomic. There are many like it the paper. The claim that an an odd number of zero modes    makes the path integral measure change sign under  a gauge transformation by the central element $-1\in {\rm SU}(2)$ is likewise a mystery. The measure has both a $d\bar \psi_0$ and $d\psi_0$ for each zero mode, and so is invariant under the simultaneous transformation $\psi\to -\psi$ and $\bar\psi \to -\bar \psi$. Further, while it  is clear that  the mod 2 index of the five dimensional Dirac operator connects to  the *five* dimensional  operator $(-1)^F$, (which comes from the mapping torus periodic boundary condition in the $S^1$ direction) and is given by the ordinary *four* dimensional index reduced mod 2,  I do not  see how they  can claim that this  relates to  the *four* dimensional $(-1)^F$ which is not well defined on $S^4$.      I look forward to some interesting answers to your question.